# How do I force an input to be in upper case in a batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I know that to make an input in be read in upper case in python is:
(example)

```
    input = input('example input').upper()
    if inupt == 'YES':
        start()
    else:
        input == 'NO':
            end()
```

but how do I do this, or something similar in Batch?

Comment: Do you need it to be upper case for other parts of the script, or would you be okay with just doing a case-insensitive comparison?

Comment: I need it to be uppercase for other parts.